# Error Testing DotNet Project on Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to setup a build on azure devops to suppress flaky tests and continue going through the the tasks, but the test section that I got from the documentation fails regardless of what I try and do

I setup my test section based off of this document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive

specifically lifting this block

```
steps:
# ...
# do this after your tests have run
- script: dotnet test <test-project> --logger trx
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    testRunner: VSTest
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'
```

I get this error message

> ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.

and my azure pipeline looks like this

```
parameters:
- name: solution
  type: string
- name: buildPlatform
  type: string
- name: buildConfiguration
  type: string
 

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: '5.0.x'
    packageType: 'sdk'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: ${{ parameters.solution }}
    feedsToUse: select

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: build
    includeNuGetOrg: true
    projects: ${{ parameters.solution }}
    arguments: '--configuration ${{ parameters.buildConfiguration }}' 

- script: dotnet test ${{ parameters.solution }} --logger trx
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    testRunner: VSTest
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'   

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'copy build'
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: |
      **/*
      !.git/**/*
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'publish artifact'
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: drop

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'zip nuget packages'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_nupkgs'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/NugetPackages.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'publish nuget packages'
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/NugetPackages.zip'
    artifactName: nugetPackages
```

Comment: Your test is being run by the line `- script: dotnet test ${{ parameters.solution }} --logger trx` . Have you passed the solution file parameter into the script?

Did you know that you can use another script to output your variable names to check they are set correctly, something like:

  - script: |
      echo 'name - ${{ parameters.solution}}'
      echo 'name - ${{ parameters.buildPlatform}}'

Comment: Yes I've checked that the parameter is being passed correctly, as all the steps that use that parameter before test works fine